# ESLint, indent, and ignoreNodes - trouble getting AST selectors to work correctly

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, abstract-syntax-tree

As TSLint is being deprecated, I'm in the process of converting projects to use ESLint instead.

I'd like to set my indentation rules to allow this:

```
type HtmlColor = 'attrib' | 'background' | 'bg_whitespace' | 'comment' | 'entity' | 'error' | 'foreground' |
                 'invalid' | 'markup' | 'tag' | 'value' | 'warning' | 'whitespace';
```

I'm currently getting an error about the indentation of the second line, that it should be 0 spaces instead of 17. I might have expected the error to complain that it wasn't 2 spaces, but certainly not 0.

At any rate, if I can't get the specific indentation I want recognized, I'd at least like to have indentation ignored in this case.

I've tried to fix this using the `ignoredNodes` option for the ESLint `indent` rule like this:

```
    "@typescript-eslint/indent": [
      "error",
      2,
      {
        "ArrayExpression": "first",
        "FunctionDeclaration": { parameters: "first" },
        "ignoredNodes": [
          "ArrowFunction > Block",
          "NoSubstitutionTemplateLiteral",
          "TemplateLiteral",
          "TypeAliasDeclaration *"
        ],
        "ObjectExpression": "first",
        "VariableDeclarator": "first",
        "SwitchCase": 1
      }
    ],
```

I can see that *part* of the `ignoredNodes` list is working like I expect, such as the `"TemplateLiteral"` part, but I can't figure out the right AST syntax to deal with the `type` declaration, and other things like arrow functions either.

I've used the [AST Explorer](https://astexplorer.net/) to help figure out what the AST selectors should be, but with no luck so far.

Answer (score 5):

I found the syntax I was looking for:

```
        "ignoredNodes": [
          "ArrowFunctionExpression > BlockStatement",
          "NoSubstitutionTemplateLiteral",
          "TemplateLiteral",
          "TSTypeAliasDeclaration *"
        ],
```

The trick was realizing that different settings for [AST Explorer](https://astexplorer.net/) produce *different node names* for the same TypeScript language constructs! Until I specifically set AST Explorer to use `@typescript-eslint/parser`, and not just `typescript`, and a Transform of "ESLint v4", I was getting the wrong selector names in the parse tree generated from my TypeScript code.

Comment: I have a similar problem but for some other nodes. Are all four of those selectors needed to make your example work? If so, can you elborate why and how you figured it out?